# Prove there is a unique $x_0 \in M$ such that $\|x_0 - z\| = \inf_{x \in M} \|x-z\|$ and show $z-x_0 \perp M$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove there is a unique $x_0 \in M$ such that $$\|x_0 - z\| = \inf_{x \in M} \|x-z\|$$ and show $z-x_0 \perp M$.

Here, $X$ is a finite dimensional inner product space and $M$ is a proper, nonempty closed linear subspace of $X$ and $z\in X$.

I've been thinking about this for a bit and I'm not really sure what to do with it. I feel like $x_0$ should be in $M$ because $M$ is closed but I'm not really sure. Any ideas or hints that could help me figure this out?

Comment: You say that $x_0 \in M$ at the very start. Moreover in a finite dimension every subspace is closed.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews it says *explicitly* that $X$ is finite dimensional. We can just as well assume the closed is redundant.

Comment: Yeah, missed that @quid Somehow saw the "closed" and assumed the question was asking about arbitrary inner product spaces.

Comment: @quid so from what I gather it was correct to say $x_0 \in M$ since M is closed?

Comment: You could argue the existence by first asserting that any element of norm greater than say $10||z||$ certainly will not be the infimum. Then restrict to $m \in M$ and $||m|| \le 10||z||$ which is compact (since bounded and closed) so that a continuous function attains a minimum.  // Again, closed is redundant when your space is finite dimensional. If you space is in fact not finite dimensional please correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $m,x_1\in M$, and $\alpha=m\cdot (x_1-z)\neq 0$, let $$x_2=x_1-\frac{\alpha}{\|m\|} m$$

Then $x_2\in M$, and 
$$\begin{align}
(x_2-z)\cdot(x_2-z) &= (x_1-z)\cdot(x_1-z)-2(x_1-z)\cdot\left(\frac{\alpha}{\|m\|}m\right) + \alpha^2\\
&=\|x_1-z\|^2 -\alpha^2 < \|x_1-z\|^2
\end{align}$$

So if $x_0$ exists, $z-x_0$ must be orthogonal to all elements of $M$.

If $x_1$ and $x_0$ are two elements of $M$ with the requested property, then:

$$(x_1-x_0)\cdot m = ((x_1-z)-(x_0-z))\cdot m = 0$$ for all $m$. But $x_1-x_0\in M$, and $x_1-x_0$ is perpendicular to every element of $M$. This means that $(x_1-x_0)\cdot(x_1-x_0)=0$, so $x_1=x_0$.

So you are left proving that such an element $x_0$ exists, and then we'll know it is unique and $z-x_0\perp M$.

For any $n>0$, find $x_n\in M$ so that $$\|z-x_n\|< \frac{1}{n} + \inf_{x\in M} \|z-x\|$$ This $x_n$ exists by definition of $\inf$. Show that $\{x_1,\dots\}$ is bounded, and thus must have a convergent sub-sequence. Call the value it converges to $x_0$, and show that $\|z-x_0\|< \frac{1}{n} + \inf_{x\in M} \|z-x\|$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

By drawing a picture and recalling basic geometric facts one can see that $x_0$ should be the orthogonal projection of $x$ on $M$.

Indeed, if $x_0$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ on $M$ and $m \in M$, then 
$||m -x||^2 = ||m -x_0||^2 +  ||x -x_0||^2$ by the Pythagorean theorem, which holds in any inner product space.

The orthogonal projection can be found as $\sum_i \langle x , m_i \rangle m_i $ where $(m_i)_i$ is an orthonormal  basis of $M$. (Note this is finite.)

Comment: Drawing pictures is problematic when dealing with infinite dimensional spaces. You say "if $x_0$ is the orthoganl projection of $x$ on $M$..." but you are simply asserting such a point exists.

Comment: Drawing pictures is for gaining intuition. The space is according to OP finite dimensional. The final paragraph gives an explicit formula for the orthogonal projection. (Perhaps  you missed this as I added with some delay though well before you posted your comment.)